# Magento2 404 page not display

Tags: magento-2.1, 404-page

I have set 404 page in admin stores > configuration but for some reason its not loading 404 page , its throwing following error:

Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

how can i display the 404 page not found instead of this error on same URL.

[image: Here is the Image of error]

Comment: Did you modified root .htaccess file ?

Comment: no i didn't change .htaccess.. BTW i am working on localhost.

Comment: any module you are using which is doing  redirection like geoip or any other module which can alter behaviour of routers ?

Comment: its a fresh install.